# Android - Webview scale image to fit biggest dimension

Tags: image, webview, scale

In my ever so harsh endeavor to make my own apps, i have hit yet another brick wall.

***Details***

I decided today since the `WebView` already has build in zoom controls that i would migrate to it from a `ImageView`...my issue is that I still have active user with API 3 running...so I have to keep that in mind when writing update for this app

***What am i trying to do?***

Simply load an image from my server and display it fitting to the `WebView` window which can vary in size depending on the screen.

***What have you tried***

***Try #1 (my personal attempt)***

```
//iW & iH are the height and width of the image passed from the server
//Calc the scale needed to fit width
int scW = (int) ((iW / (float)wView.getMeasuredHeight()) * 100);
//Calc the scale needed to fit height
int scH = (int) ((iH / (float)wView.getMeasuredHeight()) * 100);
//fit the bigger of the 2
if (scW < scH)
{
    wView.setInitialScale(scW);
}
else
{
    wView.setInitialScale(scH);
}
String pUrl = "http://app.guycothal.com/Funnys/2012724133312929.png";
wView.loadUrl(pUrl);
```

This leaves some pics with a lot of empty space on all pics

***Try #2 (Found on StackOverFlow)***

```
String pUrl = "http://app.guycothal.com/Funnys/2012724133312929.png";
String html="<html><body><img src=\"" + pUrl + 
    "\" width=\"10%37\" height=\"10%37\"/></body></html>";
wView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

This makes the images HUGE...and i mean ***HUGE***

***Try #3(Found on StackOverFlow)***

```
wView.setWebViewClient(null);
wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);//NEeds api 7
wView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
wView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
wView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);//Needs api 5
String pUrl = "http://app.guycothal.com/Funnys/2012724133312929.png";
wView.loadUrl(pUrl);
```

Other than needing and API higher than 3...even without those lines, it make the image again HUGE

***Try #4 (again found HERE!!! <--- at least i search first)***

```
wView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
String pUrl = "http://app.guycothal.com/Funnys/2012724133312929.png";
wView.loadUrl(pUrl);
```

Still needs Froyo (API 7) or higher

_**Try #5 (Tried while writing this question after thinking too long)**

```
//iW & iH are the height and width of the image passed from the server
int iMW = imgView.getMeasuredWidth();
int iMH = imgView.getMeasuredHeight();
int scW = (int) ((iW / (float)iMW) * 100);
int scH = (int) ((iH / (float)iMH) * 100);
if (iMW < iW && iMH < iH)
{
    if (scW < scH)
    {
        wView.setInitialScale(scW);
    }
    else
    {
        wView.setInitialScale(scH);
    }
}
if (iMW < iW && iMH > iH)
{
    wView.setInitialScale(scH);
}
if (iMW > iW && iMH < iH)
{
    wView.setInitialScale(scW);
}
if (iMW < iW && iMH < iH)
{
    if (scW > scH)
    {
        wView.setInitialScale(scW);
    }
    else
    {
        wView.setInitialScale(scH);
    }
}
wView.loadUrl(pUrl);
```

***Whats Next?***

I have no clue where to go from here...i have been killing myself all day over this one simple thing...please help before i pull my hair out

***p.s. I am bald...so the hair this is a joke***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Try #5 Worked!!!***

```
        int iMW = imgView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int iMH = imgView.getMeasuredHeight();
        //Had the imw and iw backward...same for height
        int scW = (int) ((iMW / (float)iW) * 100); 
        int scH = (int) ((iMH / (float)iH) * 100);
        int fScale = 0;
        if (iMW < iW && iMH < iH)
        {
            if (scW < scH)
            {
                fScale = scW;
            }
            else
            {
                fScale = scH;
            }
        }
        if (iMW < iW && iMH > iH)
        {
            fScale = scW;
        }
        if (iMW > iW && iMH < iH)
        {
            fScale = scH;
        }
        //had signs backwards...DUH
        if (iMW > iW && iMH > iH)
        {
            if (scW < scH)
            {
                fScale = scW;
            }
            else
            {
                fScale = scH;
            }
        }
        wView.setInitialScale(fScale);
        wView.loadUrl(pUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me fix a very similar issue :))